# How to remove in-line style of Wordpress's post content only?

Tags: posts, css, blog

My previous blog author using his font-family and size on every sentence of blog post. I want apply new css rule to post but it cant overide these in-line styles.

I tried searching around and found this one:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', function( $content ){
  return str_replace( ' style="', ' data-style="', $content);
});
```

But it removing style of whole website. I just want remove style that used on single post's content only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to remove the style from single post. And the "single post" term is confusing.
Whether you need it for a single post or the single post template.

In either case you have to use your code with conditional and your code may look like this.

***If you want to remove from all posts(not pages but including custom post types).***

```
add_filter( 'the_content', function( $content ){

    if(is_single()){

        return str_replace( ' style="', ' data-style="', $content); 

    }

    else{

       return $content;

    }

});
```

***If you want to remove from all posts(only WordPress post, not custom post type or pages).***

```
add_filter( 'the_content', function( $content ){

    if (is_singular('post')) {

          return str_replace( ' style="', ' data-style="', $content);

    }  
    else{

       return $content;

    }
});
```

`is_singular` is the WordPress API conditional to check post types.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_singular/

***If you want to remove from only one particular post.***

```
add_filter( 'the_content', function( $content ){

    if(is_single([POST-ID])){

          return str_replace( ' style="', ' data-style="', $content);

    }
    else{

       return $content;

    }
});
```

Comment: Follow your instruction. I added this code to my theme function.php. But it's not working

if(is_single()){

add_filter( 'the_content', function( $content ){
  return str_replace( ' style="', ' data-style="', $content);
});

}

Comment: @HiểnHồ The conditionals will be inside the add_filter block. See the code, I have modified it above. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you man. You really kind for helping me. But i tried you both above codes, its remove style of pages also.

Comment: Yes you are right. I have not checked the pages. I have modified the code and its working fine for me now. Tested on latest ver.

Comment: so happy with my blog now. your code worked well. thank again Behemoth

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code it works better

```
add_filter('the_content', function( $content ){
    $content = preg_replace('/ style=("|\')(.*?)("|\')/','',$content);
    return $content;
}, 20);
```

Comment: But this one will replace all in-line style of pages also. I just want to  remove styles of WordPress post only